# Why can't I login to my Symphony 2.3.1 admin panel?

Tags: authentication, symphony-cms

I upgraded from Symphony 2.2.5 to Symphony 2.3.1. I have not been able to login to a project on Mac OS 10.8.3 on any of the following browsers:

- Safari
- Chrome
- Firefox
- Opera

I'm looking into the [localhost solution in comment #11 on the Symphony Forum](http://getsymphony.com/discuss/thread/62821/#position-11).

Per [Can't get to admin area](http://getsymphony.com/discuss/thread/24044/#position-20), I can confirm that my .htaccess is for 2.3.x.

The /lib/core/class.session.php file is as it should be per [this comment](http://getsymphony.com/discuss/thread/24044/2/#position-24).

I'd also add that when I login with a known INCORRECT password I receive the normal Symphony error notification, "The login details provided are incorrect." However, when I enter the known CORRECT password, the form posts, gives no feedback, and does not login or redirect.

Further, the hash in the `password` field (table: `sym_authors`) is changed upon entering the known CORRECT password to `PBKDF2v1|10000|29846548654be8d15328|zCZ+`. I know we're using salt now, but this doesn't look salted though it is SHA-1 length (40 char).

Any help you can give is greatly appreciated.

---

### Articles consulted

- [localhost solution in comment #11 on the Symphony Forum](http://getsymphony.com/discuss/thread/62821/#position-11)
- [Can't get to admin area](http://getsymphony.com/discuss/thread/24044/#position-20)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug in which the password column in `tbl_authors` was not correctly extended to be of 150 characters in length during the update process. You can manually edit this in the `tbl_authors` table.

This is a known bug and will be fixed in the next release!